# On graph data is there any way to add margin between nodes and links

Tags: echarts

I would like to put a space between nodes and connection lines on graph chart.

I tried to draw custom connection links between nodes, but there is no way to do that or I couldn't find anything.

Look at this example and imagine that the lines are not touching the nodes.
Ex: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph&reset=1&edit=1

[image]

Fallowing example which provided by Mathias works great but if I put roam: true as a property for both series, both series switched to draggable mode but the problem is they are not moves synchronously.

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'graph',
      symbolSize: 70,
      roam: true,
      label: {show: true},
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black'
      },
      data: [
        {name: 'A', x: 0, y: 0},
        {name: 'B', x: 10, y: 0},
        {name: 'C', x: 5, y: 7}
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'graph',
      silent: true,
      roam: true,
      symbolSize: 100,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      },
      z: 0,
      edgeSymbol: ['none', 'arrow'],
      lineStyle:{
        color: '#000000',
        curveness: 0.2,
        width: 3,
      },
      data: [
        {name: 'A', x: 0, y: 0},
        {name: 'B', x: 10, y: 0},
        {name: 'C', x: 5, y: 7}
      ],
      links: [
        {source: 'A', target: 'B', lineStyle: {curveness: -0.2}},
        {source: 'A', target: 'C'},
        {source: 'B', target: 'C'},
        {source: 'C', target: 'A'}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a second series of invisable helper nodes to put the links on and make them larger than the original nodes. Here is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5AOY4CGIAFkwDRUUMtALYAjYABsAyhABejWAHYADP2roJ7UVgnEkGLsADuxMDgCuWAL5r1EMFmFS6EhanUUAxpOA5mAYgAzYL4BanEcABNcAHUISLAuYgBGWw8I6JwAYR8_WCZRTU8AayYw2BtyyPYwdmIyD3QkaHZhBSYAQT5YAA9iVVhafsrG5Ba25gAhbr7YZIGh2GURxubW9qyZ4gBWXkHiRStygF0BFabyugZmNk4eNMEIV2gwUwssB_QhMUkZeRTlKpyvZHM5aK49OV0N4JL4AsFAmUPOcKLJ-p9YFhIiwsFIROJdKQmNAYFhukx2DgcMYmMcMRIINBcS5GO5GjC4fl_ICecpQqNPOYcAA3LBMjBEJYAOgATBj0EZ4oliABmDEo9DVWr1KFjdbMLp7WYLYbyvUTfLTI0AvaLZZmtYWpiba2wXb7JRHDx08oM6DFSUNVYYYBCzztQ00Sk416W7p-5ngtyCkVigiSgC0yllVg1FH0oZw4YN3VqOBjzE2eaaIbD7StUfLWFjzqY1eQtaLG1L0ebJa96lO1AHpysAG4gA):

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'graph',
      symbolSize: 70,
      label: {show: true},
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black'
      },
      data: [
        {name: 'A', x: 0, y: 0},
        {name: 'B', x: 10, y: 0},
        {name: 'C', x: 5, y: 7}
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'graph',
      silent: true,
      symbolSize: 100,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      },
      z: 0,
      edgeSymbol: ['none', 'arrow'],
      lineStyle:{
        color: '#000000',
        curveness: 0.2,
        width: 3,
      },
      data: [
        {name: 'A', x: 0, y: 0},
        {name: 'B', x: 10, y: 0},
        {name: 'C', x: 5, y: 7}
      ],
      links: [
        {source: 'A', target: 'B', lineStyle: {curveness: -0.2}},
        {source: 'A', target: 'C'},
        {source: 'B', target: 'C'},
        {source: 'C', target: 'A'}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

If you can live without the arrows on the links you could use an invisable border:

```js
itemStyle: {
  borderWidth: 20,
  borderColor: '#fff',
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias, that's great if I hadn't use it with the "roam: true" feature. Thanks for sharing. This probably won't work if the user wants to drag something. But your implementation is a nice sollution for static graphs.

Comment: There is an [official example](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/how-to/interaction/drag) on dragging interaction and you certainly can move the invisable "helper" nodes according to the other ones. So I see no reason why it wouldnt work for dragging.